# No module named 'selenium.webdriver.safari.options'

Tags: safaridriver, selenium4

| Requirements |  |
| --- | --- |
| OS | macOS Monterey 12.3.1 |
| Selenium version | 4.1.1 |
| Python | 3.10 |
| Safari | 15.4 (17613.1.17.1.13) |

```
from selenium.webdriver.safari.options import Options as SafariOptions
self.options = SafariOptions()
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.safari.options'

and I can't use desired_capabilities in selenium4 because:

```
        if desired_capabilities:
        warnings.warn(
            "desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object with options kwarg",
            DeprecationWarning,
            stacklevel=2
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari Options was a known bug for Selenium 4 for Py.

This has been resolved - [Py safari options #10385](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/10385)

This was merged into release 4.1.3 for Py, update your Selenium version to 4.1.3 or 4.1.4 to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to install auto-gpt, I recommend you to create a new environment and execute requirement.txt file.This was the way I solved the issue.